# Help to identify this imparipinnated cutting

Tags: identification

I just got this cutting. I know I have seen before, but I can not remember what species it is.

As you can see from pictures there are no flower nor buds that may help to identify it. Since I don't know if roots are well established, I do not like to take picture of them. By the way I think that leaves show a nutritional deficit (maybe due to a small root system) and therefore its natural color could be different.

---

**Edit:**

The cutting was a gift. The original owner has not watered it and apparently died (as you can see in first picture there is a dry stem). Later it sprouted again. Neither the original owner nor who gifted it... know what it is.

[image: general/detail]
[image: general]
[image: upside/leaves]
[image: downside/leaves]

Comment: Is it a native species?

Comment: @J.Musser native from Canary Islands? I think it is not. From Spain or Europe? I have no idea.

Comment: Do you know where you got it? It appeared in your hands overnight? :)

Comment: When you say you 'can not remember what species it is', does that imply that you knew at one point?

Comment: @J.Musser see my updated question. And yes it is familiar to me (most likely a commercial plant).

Comment: If it regrew that well, it definitely has some roots. I'd fertilize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It reminds me strongly of Jasminum humile 'revolutum', though the leaves seem a little too short and a little pale, though that could be the deficiency you mention. The slightly square look of the stem and its 'grooved' appearance are the same though, along with the leaf arrangement.

Comment: Quite right! The lovely _Jasminum humile_ L. cv. Revolutum. I think the color and size of leaves are normal after one year without cares in the small pot.

Comment: @ondoteam - one of my favourite plants, just a shame it has no scent.

Comment: I remember it is scented, not very strong like Jasminum polyanthum Franch., but scented. Can you join the chat?

Comment: @ondoteam - er, yea, if I can work out how to get in there...